# How can I ignore occurrences of : in an input?

Tags: java, input, run-length-encoding

How can I ignore parts of an input in Java? I have to take input and transform it so that I can transform from an RLE String such as

```
28:10:6B:10:10:AB:10:2B:10:12B:10:2B:10:5B:20:11B:10:6B:10
```

into an RLE Hex data such as

```
28106B10AB102B10CB102B105B20BB106B10
```

Can anyone help me do it? It does not have to be strictly by ignoring it, any other way than can do the job works.

Comment: That's not hex data; last I checked "12B" and "11B" are not bytes. Since it's string data, you may as well use the separator if it's available. Chances are that separation is important.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
String text = "28:10:6B:10:10B:10:2B:10:12B:10:2B:10:5B:20:11B:10:6B:10"

String result = text.replace(":", "");
```

Comment: He also needs to convert stuff like the "12" in "12B" to hexadecimal though. He needs those separators.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add one more thing to the already provided answers:

You have the option to use either the 'replace' or the 'replaceAll' methods. The '**replaceAll**' uses regular expression. But it is simpler and lighter  to use the '**replace**'.

```
String text = "28:10:6B:10:10B:10:2B:10:12B:10:2B:10:5B:20:11B:10:6B:10";

String result1 = text.replace(":", "");

String result2 = text.replaceAll("\\:", "");
```